# Output of well-known algorithms for the Subset sum problem

Tags: algorithms, knapsack-problems

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem):

> In computer science, the subset sum problem is an important problem in complexity theory and cryptography. The problem is this: given a set (or multiset) of integers, is there a non-empty subset whose sum is zero? For example, given the set {−7, −3, −2, 5, 8}, **the answer is yes because the subset {−3, −2, 5} sums to zero**. The problem is NP-complete.

What is the **output** of the known algorithms which resolve **exactly** the subset sum problem?

For example:

- The algorithm which take $O(2^N*N)$ time.
- The algorithme which take $O(2^{N/2})$ time.

Is it just **Yes / No** or do they also give **the extraction of solution**?

Example:

$A = \{1, 3, 4, 5\}$

$k = 8$ (The search item)

- Output : YES
- Output : {1,3,4}, {5,3} (where 1+3+4=8 and 5+3=8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question "is there a subset that sums up to $t$?" has a YES/NO answer. In general, we shouldn't expect an algorithm to do more than it is asked to, so to speak. However, it is rather common that when an algorithm answers YES, it can also naturally give you a certificate that proves it. Moreover, when this happens, you typically get a *one* valid solution. (This was just a clarification because your example outputs 2 valid solutions. Listing *all* solutions is a different thing).

Both algorithms you mention explicitly step through certain subsets, and so it is easy for them to also output the subset whose elements sum up to $t$. Whether you care about that extra information is up to you then.

Comment: Also, given an algorithm for the decision version of SUBSET-SUM, we can use it as a black box to solve the search version.

Comment: When you say "both algorithms" do you know which ones @csblo may be referring to? The top one I suppose it's just a brute force search e.g. the power set of all elements is $2^n@$ and a brute-force sum (or check) for each subset would be $N$, so we end up with $O(2^N N)$. But what about the algorithm that runs in $O(2^{N/2})$, do you know what algorithm he may be referring to?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Just reading your comment above, the runtime complexity of that solution using SUBSET-SUM as a black box can be _very_ different for the decision problem right?

Comment: @Josh The other one is probably the one due to Horowitz and Sahni - it's quite simple as well.

Comment: @Josh Not really. It is at most a factor of $n$ slower, where $n$ is the number of elements. Given that algorithms for subset sum run in exponential time, it's not a big difference.